# When using bytes.replace is there a way to use wildcards?

Tags: printing, replace, byte, go, wildcard

I am programming in Go and I read a text file in and I replace multiple things on it to translate the code from one language to Go to be able to run. The problem I am having is that when trying to replace things like Println statements I cannot get a parenthesis on the end of the statement without being really specific to the code I am converting. Is there a way to use  the code like this?

```
src = bytes.Replace(src, []byte("Insert"), []byte("Println(" * ")"), -1)
```

and have the ability to just put a parenthesis at the end of the line of code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
package main

import (
        "fmt"
        "regexp"
)

func main() {
        src := []byte(`
Write(1, 3, "foo", 3*qux(42));
WriteLn("Enter bar: ");
`)
        re := regexp.MustCompile(`Write\((.*)\);`)
        re2 := regexp.MustCompile(`WriteLn\((.*)\);`)
        src = re.ReplaceAll(src, []byte(`Print($1)`))
        src = re2.ReplaceAll(src, []byte(`PrintLn($1)`))
        fmt.Printf("%s", src)
}
```

(Alse [here](http://play.golang.org/p/h7tDbWfjvZ))

---

Output:

```
Print(1, 3, "foo", 3*qux(42))
PrintLn("Enter bar: ")
```

Comment: Now with this will I be able to set it to the variable src to update it as I make changes to the code?